# postgresql and INSERT variables

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, postgresql-9.2

I'm close but stuck. I pull the user name from drupal and store it in a variable called $username, I want to store this in a column called username. However the below code throws up an error

```
        $sql = "INSERT INTO sheet_tbl (site_id, user_id, eventdate, eventtime, username) VALUES ('$_POST[site_id]','$_POST[user_id]','$_POST[eventdate]','$_POST[eventtime]',$username)";
```

Error

```
warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" at character 112 in /var/www/html/drupal1/includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code on line 30.
```

I pull the user name using:

```
 User Name: <?php 
 global $user;
 echo $user->name;
 $username = $user->name;
 ?>
```

If i echo this variable i get the result = admin

Comment: Try `echo $sql;`just after assigning the string and let us know the output

Comment: Record addedINSERT INTO sheet_tbl (site_id, user_id, eventdate, eventtime, username) VALUES ('14','1','29/06/2012','20:44',)

Comment: That is with the results from the code in my question @OscarPérez

Comment: See my answer. The problem is `,)`, as your username variable is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not put `username` in quotes. Replace

```
,$username)";
```

with

```
,'$username')";
```

And BTW you should not put unescaped user input in your SQL statements. That can lead to SQL injections. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure without vieweing the output of `echo $sql;`, but I guess the problem is the way you're accessing the `$POST` array.

Try this:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO sheet_tbl (site_id, user_id, eventdate, eventtime, \"username\")"
          ." VALUES ('$_POST[site_id]', "
          ."         '$_POST[user_id]',"
          ."         '$_POST[eventdate]',"
          ."         '$_POST[eventtime]',"
          ."          '$username')";
```

Edit: corrected syntax

Comment: warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information at character 150 in /var/www/html/drupal1/includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code on line 33.

Comment: I just tried this $sql = "INSERT INTO sheet_tbl (site_id, user_id, eventdate, eventtime, username) VALUES ('$_POST[site_id]','$_POST[user_id]','$_POST[eventdate]','$_POST[eventtime]', username='$username')";

Comment: i changed the syntax... could you give it a try?

Comment: warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: column "username" does not exist at character 113 in /var/www/html/drupal1/includes/common.inc(1743) : eval()'d code on line 31.

Comment: Although I know the column does exist as i can see it

Comment: Do you have a `username`column in your `shet_tbl` table?

Comment: If so, use `"username"` as column name